# Nodes become opaque when selected in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

How can I make the selected node stay transparent? (Viewer Node selected)
Sorry for the dumb question xd

Comment: Hi :). It's one of the fields in Preferences > Themes > Node Editor ;).

Comment: I don't think there is an option for that there?
Because I had to change an option in Themes to begin with to get the nodes to be transparent but I haven't seen an option for opacity when node is selected